# How do I do this in Jquery? It's about classes and adding something to the tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Average_rating = a number between 1 and 5
</script>
<select name="rate">
         <option value="1" class="p_rating_star" />Not so great</option>
         <option value="2" class="p_rating_star" />Quite good</option>
         <option value="3" class="p_rating_star" />Good</option>
         <option value="4" class="p_rating_star" />Great!</option>
         <option value="5" class="p_rating_star" />Excellent!</option>
</select>
```

I am building a rating system.

How do I use JQuery to add **"selected = selected"**  to one of the option values, depending on the average_rating?

How can I say...

```
Add "selected = selected" to anything with class "p_rating_star" where average_rating = that class's value (1-5)?
```

Comment: not question related - your <option> syntax is incorrect - you're incorrectly closing them with />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".p_rating_star[value=" + average_rating + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[value=' + Average_rating + '].p_rating_star').attr('selected', 'selected');
```